# Python executable: FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I have a python script that is running perfectly.

I tried to convert it into an EXE executable using pyinstaller and it is giving me the error -

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './image/Some_Name_logos_transparent.png'`

Here is an example of where this file is being used -

```
logo_image = Image.open(r'./image/Some_Name_logos_transparent.png')
```

I don't understand how the python script is working perfectly fine, but the exe is not working.

I know about the `os.path.join` command, but I don't know if the problem is with the file's location or if I am missing something when converting it to the executable.

**Edit** - Well, I forgot to place the images in the directory as  given in the code. My friend made this script and he was at his wit's end because he was unable to compile the script to an exe, so I was trying to help him out.

But, I guess I could have figured it out easily from the error.

Regardless, the answers seem very useful for debugging purposes so I am thinking of not deleting this (Also because I don't think I can actually delete it)

And I am sorry for wasting people's time.

Comment: Start off by printing your current working directory like `print(os.getcwd())`, then see if it's the folder where you expect the `image` folder to be, and the image file as well.

Comment: You are looking for the `image` directory inside your working directory. Your executable should work as long as it's inside the directory where `images` exist. But if you copy/move it to somewhere else it will not be able to find the `image` directory. Is that the case?

Comment: Yup! 

I realised just now. I have edited the question

Answer (score 3):

If you are building to a single EXE file and the file you want to access is included in that, you can try this:

```py
import sys, os
actual_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, original_relative_path)
```

On execution, all files from the exe archive are decompressed into a temp folder. `sys._MEIPASS` points to that directory.

See also here: [Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile)

If it's a different file, try using the full path.

EDIT:

here is a code snipped that works in normal execution and from exe file:

```py
def translate_path(file):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        file_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, file)
    else:
        file_path = os.path.abspath(file)

    return file_path
```

Also PyInstaller docs has more information on that topic: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html

Comment: Turns out that I forgot to place the images in the specified directory
But, your answer seems very useful if I had an actual error.